# XCTest and Swift :How to call struct name as an argument inside a function

Tags: struct, swift3, xctest

I just started with XCTest and swift recently.Would be a great help if anyone could help. I have a struct as below:

```
  struct TravelPackScreen {
        static let title = app.navigationBars.staticTexts["Hello"]
        static let checkButton = app.tables.cells.buttons["Click"]
    }
```

And I try to tap on button which works fine :

```
    func navigateToScreen() {
            TravelPackScreen.title.tap()
    }
```

Now I want to convert the above function so as to take struct name and static name as arguments in to function as below.This code throws an error as "Value of type 'String' has no member 'statiName' "

```
func navigateToScreen(strucName: String, statiName: String) {
    strucName.statiName.tap()
        }
```

Both the arguments will be string type, Is there any way we can make the above code working.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to accomplish this with Swift structs. It's possible with classes though.

Comment: Could you please help me , how it can be done with classes, and what would be I losing if I implement class instead of structs?

Comment: Search for `NSClassFromString`. And about the difference between structs and classes you can find a ton of articles in the internet and even the ebook by Apple discusses this in length.